# Mask R-CNN optimizer and learning rate scheduler in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

In the Mask R-CNN paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06870#:%7E:text=The%20method%2C%20called%20Mask%20R,CNN%2C%20running%20at%205%20fps.) the optimizer is described as follows training on MS COCO 2014/2015 dataset for instance segmentation (I believe this is the dataset, correct me if this is wrong)

> We train on 8 GPUs (so effective minibatch
> size is 16) for 160k iterations, with a learning rate of
> 0.02 which is decreased by 10 at the 120k iteration. We
> use a weight decay of 0.0001 and momentum of 0.9. With
> ResNeXt [45], we train with 1 image per GPU and the same
> number of iterations, with a starting learning rate of 0.01.

I'm trying to write an optimizer and learning rate scheduler in Pytorch for a similar application, to match this description.

For the optimizer I have:

```
def get_Mask_RCNN_Optimizer(model, learning_rate=0.02):
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0001)
    return optimizer
```

For the learning rate scheduler I have:

```
def get_MASK_RCNN_LR_Scheduler(optimizer, step_size):
    scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=step_size, gammma=0.1, verbose=True)
    return scheduler
```

When the authors say "decreased by 10" do they mean divide by 10? Or do they literally mean subtract by 10, in which case we have a negative learning rate, which seems odd/wrong. Any insights appreciated.

Comment: They mean "divide by 10". As you pointed out yourself, subtracting 10 is an absurd operation is this context. Dividing the learning by values like 2, 5 or 10 is very common in the litterature. The smaller the learning rate is, the more precise your convergence is (but the slower it is as well). This paper decreases the LR only once, but a lot of trainings use a regular reduction, like dividing by ten every N epochs, or when the convergence stops

Comment: @trialNerror if you post this as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authors mean divide by 10, as pointed out in the comments.